# How to fix java.lang.StackOverflowError in simple Quicksort without setting array.lenght-1?

Tags: java, arrays, quicksort

Problem:
I implemented a quicksort algorithm that unfortunatly just works for some `int[]` and then breaks. I get the error `StackOverflowError`

What I tried so far:
I have to call the `sort(array[], left, right)` without the `A[r]`
I cannot modify the  `sort(array, 0, array.length);` to  `sort(array, 0, array.length-1)`. My idea was to call a new function that returns length - 1 and attach it to the variable right;
It works just for some `int[]` and then breaks.

My code:

```java
private static class Quicksort {

    private void sort(int[] array, int left, int right) {           
        right = lenRight(array); //to get array.lenght-1
        int l = left;
        int r = right;
        int pivot = array[right];

        // die Partition
        while (l <= r) {
            while (array[l] < pivot)
                l++;
            while (array[r] > pivot)
                r--;

            // die swap
            if (l <= r) {
                int temp = array[l];
                array[l] = array[r];
                array[r] = temp;
                l++; 
                r--;
            }
        }
        if (left < r)
            sort(array, left, r); // where it breaks
        if (right > l)
            sort(array, l, right);
    }

    public int lenRight(int[] array) {
        return array.length - 1;
    }

    public void sort(int[] array) {
        sort(array, 0, array.length);
    }
}
```

My error

```
    Testing array [30, 88]
    PASS
    Testing array [75, 35]
    PASS
    Testing array [15, 62]
    PASS
    Testing array [52, 55, 46]
    PASS
    Testing array [18, 22, 56]
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at Sorting$Quicksort.sort(Sorting.java:36)
        at Sorting$Quicksort.sort(Sorting.java:36)
        at Sorting$Quicksort.sort(Sorting.java:36)
        at Sorting$Quicksort.sort(Sorting.java:36)
        at Sorting$Quicksort.sort(Sorting.java:36)
        at Sorting$Quicksort.sort(Sorting.java:36)
        at Sorting$Quicksort.sort(Sorting.java:36)
        at Sorting$Quicksort.sort(Sorting.java:36)
        at Sorting$Quicksort.sort(Sorting.java:36)
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger and run your code step by step?

Comment: Have a look at the parameters: you never change `left` so in the case of an already sorted array you keep passing 0 and thus `0 < r` would always be true. Then you always "reset" `right` to `array.length - 1` which is the same value for all calls (in your example it would be 2). Since the array is already sorted your "partion" loop always ends up with `l == r` before swapping so you always swap the last element with itself. In your example you'd then end up with `l == 3` and `r == 1` after swapping and since `left == 0` you're passing 0 and 1 but overwrite `right` to 2 again.

Comment: @Thomas thank you. I understood but I dont know how to fix it

Comment: You might want to revisit the quicksort algorithm in general (e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Algorithm)) but I'd do at least 2 changes: 1) don't call `right = lenRight(array);` at all but pass `array.length - 1` in your initial call and 2) only swap if `(l < r)`, i.e. if `l == r` then no swap is needed.

Answer (score 0):

The code can adjust the right parameter just after entry and when making recursive calls. Should sort be a static function?

```
    private static void sort(int[] array, int left, int right) { // static?
        right -= 1;                     // adjust
        int l = left;
        int r = right;
        int pivot = array[(l+r)/2];     // middle value better if data already sorted
          while (l <= r) {
            while (array[l] < pivot)
                l++;
            while (array[r] > pivot)
                r--;
            if (l <= r) {
                int temp = array[l];
                array[l] = array[r];
                array[r] = temp;
                l++; 
                r--;
            }
        }
        if (left < r)
            sort(array, left, r+1);     // adjust
        if (l < right)
            sort(array, l, right+1);    // adjust
    }
```